# Bootstrap 3 : add confirm modal box for jQuery Inline delete row

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have This `jQuery` function for delete row data from `MySQL`. This Worked with `jQuery confirm`, I need to add `Bootstrap 3` `modal box` confirm.

JS:

```
function deleteBox(id){
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?"))
    {
      var dataString = 'id='+ id;
      $("#flash_"+id).show();
      $("#flash_"+id).fadeIn(400).html('<img src="image/loading.gif" /> ');
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "delete.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(result){
               if(result){
                    $("#flash_"+id).hide();
                    // if data delete successfully
                    if(result=='success'){
                         //Check random no, for animated type of effect
                         var randNum=Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
                         if(randNum % 2==0){
                            // Delete with slide up effect
                            $("#list_"+id).slideUp(1000);
                         }else{
                            // Just hide data
                            $("#list_"+id).hide(500);
                         }

                    }else{
                         var errorMessage=result.substring(position+2);
                         alert(errorMessage);
                    }
              }
      }
      });
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void()"><img alt="Delete" title="Delete" width="20" src="image/delete.jpg" onclick=deleteBox("1") border="0"></a>
```

How do can i add bootstrap 3 confirm modal box for this function?!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you should implement a modal box in your html code. That modal should have two buttons (`ok` and `cancel`) with unique `id` attributes (probably inside of `modal-footer` div)

```
# your modal code around...
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="btnDeleteYes" href="#">Yes</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
  </div>
# ...
```

clicking on `btnDeleteYes` should trigger your inner logics:

```
$('#btnDeleteYes').click(function () {
    var dataString = 'id='+ id;
    $("#flash_"+id).show();
    $("#flash_"+id).fadeIn(400).html('<img src="image/loading.gif" /> ');
    # here goes your logics with ajax query and so on
    # ...
    # you may also want to hide your modal box at some point
});
```

Instead of implementing it from scratch you could also try [bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com/) which uses bootstrap modals to create dialog boxes. This would release you from the necessity of writing modals html code and implementing callbacks by hands.

Here is what your code would look like:

```
bootbox.dialog({
  message: "Are you sure you want to delete this record?",
  title: "Confirm your choice",
  buttons: {
    confirmation: {
      label: "Yes, delete it",
      className: "btn-success",
      callback: function() {
        var dataString = 'id='+ id;
        $("#flash_"+id).show();
        $("#flash_"+id).fadeIn(400).html('<img src="image/loading.gif" /> ');
        # here goes your logics with ajax query and so on
        # ...
      }
    },
    refuse: {
      label: "No, leave it alive",
    },
  }
});
```

Comment: please see my edit for HTML. I need to `onclick=deleteBox("1") ` For Dynamic id.